# how to convert telethon object to valid JSON in python

Tags: python, json, telethon

I using telethon package, for connecting and getting data from telegram.
I want to convert Message object to valid JSON.
for example, I get this object from the one API in telethon :

```
{
Message: {
    via_bot_id: None,
    entities: [],
    out: None,
    post: True,
    from_id: None,
    message: "hi everybody",
    id: 71,
    media_unread: None,
    reply_markup: None,
    fwd_from: {
        channel_id: 1119999790,
        channel_post: 2,
        date: 2017 - 09 - 04 15: 43: 48,
        from_id: None
    },
    reply_to_msg_id: None,
    edit_date: None,
    to_id: {
        channel_id: 1099583379
    },
    views: 2,
    mentioned: None,
    date: 2017 - 09 - 05 09: 28: 46,
    media: None,
    silent: None
} }
```

and this is my favorite result:

```
{
"Message": {
    "via_bot_id": "None",
    "entities": [],
    "out": "None",
    "post": "True",
    "from_id": "None",
    "message": "hi everybody",
    "id": 71,
    "media_unread": "None",
    "reply_markup": "None",
    "fwd_from": {
        "channel_id": 1119999790,
        "channel_post": 2,
        "date": "2017 - 09 - 04 15: 43: 48",
        "from_id": "None"
    },
    "reply_to_msg_id": "None",
    "edit_date": "None",
    "to_id": {
        "channel_id": 1099583379
    },
    "views": 2,
    "mentioned": "None",
    "date": "2017 - 09 - 05 09: 28: 46",
    "media": "None",
    "silent": "None"
}}
```

Is there a way to convert in Python?

Comment: what is the datatype of the date objects ? In the first example they aren't strings but in the second example they are strings ?

Comment: First code seems be invalid or its just a string but I doubt. Please check the first code or add more specific information for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem this way

I hope it will be useful for you too

for example, I get `channel` object and convert it to JSON.

`index.py`

```
import json

from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch

from helpers import date_format

api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+98XXXXXXXXXXX'
################################################
channel_username = 'tehrandb'
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash)

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
client.send_code_request(phone_number)
me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

# ---------------------------------------
my_filter = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')
all_participants = []
while_condition = True
# ---------------------------------------
channel = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel_username))
channel_dict = channel.to_dict()
json = json.dumps(channel_dict,default=date_format)
```

and `helpers.py`

```
import datetime


def date_format(message):
    """
    :param message:
    :return:
    """
    if type(message) is datetime:
        return message.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert for example every object to dict recursively:

```
def has_to_dict(obj):
   method = getattr(obj, "to_dict", None)

   return callable(method)

def to_dict_req(obj):
res = {}
if has_to_dict(obj):
    for key, value in obj.to_dict().items():
        if has_to_dict(value):
            value = to_dict_req(value)
        else:
            value = str(value)
        res[key] = value
    return res
else:
    return str(obj)
```